# I can't create apache derby DB in worklight 6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, derby

I upgraded to worklight 6.0. I added both derby_core_plugin_10_8_2,  derby_iu_doc_plugin_1.1.3, into eclipse-->plugins I restarted Eclipse and right click my project to add Apache Derby nature...nothing seems to happened, then I tried to go directly to server/java-->apache derby--> run SQL Script using "ij"...I get (the selected project does not have Apache derby nature please add it and try again)

Comment: Edit the question and describe in detail the steps you have taken and any documentation you have used.

Comment: I did edit my question

Comment: What is the reasoning behind wanting to work with Derby inside Eclipse? Derby can be used for non-production environments OUTSIDE of Eclipse. Never heard of it being used inside Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarity...It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish.

If you're trying to get worklight to run using a Derby database, then you have to modify your worklight.properties file with the following

```
wl.db.url=jdbc:derby:${worklight.home}/derby/WorklightDB;create=true
wl.db.username=dbusername
wl.db.password=dbpassword
```

If you're trying to call an SQL adapter to connect to a Derby database, then you'll need to post more information in order for us to see what it is that isn't actually working.